# WordPress - How to get posts in a category but exclude those under sub categories?

Tags: php, wordpress

Assuming the category is `A`, there are a sub category of it say `subA` which includes a post `postinsubA`

Then when i use `get_posts('category=A&...')`, all posts under category `A` also `postinsubA` are returned, but i don't wanna `postinsubA`, how can i exclude these posts in sub categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Wordpress manual, there is the query_posts() function that does have a parameter that might work for you.

Here is an example to pull only posts from category 129, but from none of the children categories of 129:

```
query_posts(array('category__in' => array(129)));
while(have_posts()) { the_post();
   echo '<li>'.the_title().'-'.the_category().'</li>';
}
```

You can also add more categories to it, like array(128,129). I did a quick test on one of my own Wordpress blog where the parent (129) had 2 posts, and the child (139) had 1 post. In printing out the loop, only the 2 posts in category 129 displayed.

Comment: Also, as a side note... If you're using Wordpress 2.6+, you can use that same parameter in get_posts() since they use the same database query class.

like: get_posts(array('category__in' => array(129)));

* Not tested *